# How can I enable "implicit evaluation" in the JetBrains Rider settings?

Tags: debugging, implicit, jetbrains-ide, evaluation, rider

JetBrains Rider does not give me the new value for my watches automatically. Instead, I have to click refresh after every step:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7Bge.png]

I went to the settings and made sure this option was enabled:

[image]

However, the problem still occurs. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: bump... apparently this is fixed but I'm also getting this to happen https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000729364-Implicit-evaliation-disabled-in-Watch-Window

Answer (score 11):

## For Rider 2020.3

1. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> twice to open **Search Anywhere**
2. Type *"refresh watched"* and hit enter <kbd>Enter</kbd>
   [image: Search Anywhere]
3. Enable *"Refresh watched values on debugger pause"*
   [image: Refresh watched values on debugger pause]

It should be enabled by default, but also ensure that *"Allow property evaluations and other implicit function calls"* is enabled first.

Answer (score 0):

Try to uncheck that mark, save, check and save again. It helped me.